# I am having trouble with windows form assignment puzzle slide

Tags: c#

I am trying to set the array for all 9 buttons to move around to the blank tile.

for example

```
this:      to this 
1 2 3      1 2 3 
4 5 6      4 5 6
7 8        7   8
```

The teacher claims she, "Don’t forget that you will need to cast sender to a Button" this is so I can be  able to swap the tiles with the blank tile as shown above. How do I do that?

Then when I reset everything back to its original location in the reset event handler, "I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Do you know how I fix that error? This is because it says the same syntax error when I try to cast sender to a Button.

Here is the following code that I hope you can fix.

```
public partial class frmSlide : Form
{
    /*
     * frmSlide -constructor
     * 
     */
    Button[,] arr = new Button[3, 3];
   
    public frmSlide()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /*
     *  allNumberButton_Click - click event handler for allNumberButton
     *  
     *  Parameter: sender -who sent the event
     *  Parameter: e -info about the event
     *  Return: nothing
     */
    private void frmSlide_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b;
        b = new Button();
        b.Location = new Point(79, 104);
        b.Width = 40;
        b.Height = 40;
        b.Text = "";
        b.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        b.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, (float)15.0);

        b.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.allNumberButton_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(b);
    }

    private void InitTwoDim(Button[,] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Button b;
                b = new Button();
                b.Location = new Point(79, 104);
                b.Width = 40;
                b.Height = 40;
                b.Text = "1";
                b.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                b.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, (float)15.0);

                b.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.allNumberButton_Click);
                this.Controls.Add(b);

                arr[i, j] = b;
            }
        }
    }

    private void allNumberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    // this is when I tried to cast button to sender to swap text but nothing happened

    {
        Button btn8 = (Button)sender;
        Button btnBlank = (Button)sender;
        string tmp;
        tmp = btn8.Text;
        btn8.Text = btnBlank.Text;
        btnBlank.Text = tmp;
    }

    /*
     *  btnReset_Click - click event handler 
     *  .text
     *  Parameter: sender -who sent the event
     *  Parameter: e -info about the event
     *  Return: nothing
     */
    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is where I tried to reset the button at its original location but got an error about' 
        //Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

        arr[0, 0].Text = "1";
        arr[0, 1].Text = "2";
        arr[0, 2].Text = "3";
        arr[0, 3].Text = "4";
        arr[1, 1].Text = "5";
        arr[1, 2].Text = "6";
        arr[1, 3].Text = "7";
        arr[2, 1].Text = "8";
        arr[2, 2].Text = " ";
    }

    /*
     *  btn1_Click -click event handler 
     *  
     *  Parameter: sender -who sent the event
     *  Parameter: e -info about the event
     *  Return: nothing
     */
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        

    }

    /*
     *  btn8_click -click event handler 
     *  
     *  Parameter: sender -who sent the event
     *  Parameter: e -info about the event
     *  Return: nothing
     */
    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btn8.Text = btnBlank.Text;
        btnBlank.Text = btn8.Text;
    }

    /*
     *  btnExit_Click -click event handler 
     *  
     *  Parameter: sender -who sent the event
     *  Parameter: e -info about the event
     *  Return: nothing
     */
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    /*
     *  frmSlide_Load- Load event handler 
     *  
     *  Parameter: sender -who sent the event
     *  Parameter: e -info about the event
     *  Return: nothing
     */
    

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Can you help me try to swap the text with the blank tile and reset all tiles back to its location? This is because im basically trying to create a slide puzzle using a two dimensional array for the 9 buttons being arranged with the blank button. This is for c#.

Comment: show us the reset logic\function.  your program isn't throwing an exception when the form loads, right?

Comment: No, just when I set the reset to its original location I get that error.

Comment: my reset function is

Comment: private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            arr[0, 0].Text = "1";
            arr[0, 1].Text = "2";
            arr[0, 2].Text = "3";
            arr[0, 3].Text = "4";
            arr[1, 1].Text = "5";
            arr[1, 2].Text = "6";
            arr[1, 3].Text = "7";
            arr[2, 1].Text = "8";
            arr[2, 2].Text = " ";
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you run your application in Debug (<kbd>F5</kbd>) (rather, with an attached debugger), you will generally see and be prompted on which line in your source is giving you the exception. (i.e. uses debug symbols to essentially map back to your source code)

The line `arr[0,0].Text = 1` (and every other reference to `arr[<column>, <row>]` usage in that scope) is going to throw an object reference exception if there are no instances of `Button` in `arr`.

Note that the line `Button[,] arr = new Button[3, 3];` dimension the array (`arr`) by defining the length and type of that 2 Dimension array of type `Button`, but it doesn't actually create\construct button instances.

---

So, to resolve this object reference exception, you need to ensure those button instances exist before attempting to use the `.Text` property.

You can do that by calling to `InitTwoDim` and passing `arr` in your form load event handler: `InitTwoDim(this.arr);` But, `this` in `this.arr` is unnecessary code, and passing the argument is also unnecessary.

The following code will refactor that method call, and move it to the class constructor.

```
public frmSlide()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeSliderButtons();
}

void InitializeSliderButtons() {
    int i = 1;
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++, i++) {
            arr[c, r] = GetNewButton(i.ToString(), c * defaultButtonWidth, r * defaultButtonHeight);
            this.Controls.Add(arr[c, r]);   
        }
    }
}

int defaultButtonWidth = 40;
int defaultButtonHeight = 40;

Button GetNewButton(string btnText, int offsetX, int offsetY) {
    var b = new Button() 
    {
        Location = new Point(79 + offsetX, 104 + offsetY),
        Width = defaultButtonWidth,
        Height = defaultButtonHeight,
        Text = btnText,
        TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
        Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, (float)15.0)
    };

    b.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.allNumberButton_Click);
    return b;
}
```

#### Noteworthy

- The click event handler is assumed to be the same for all buttons here.
- a 2D array is also 0 based indexed array.  Currently, your reset function is attempting to index with `3` (like `arr[0,3]`) that will cause a different exception (out of range).
- These `Button` instances should be added to the `Form` and their `Button.Location` assign, or `Point` instance, should be handled; I'm defining and including `offsetX` and `offsetY` as arguments on the helper to ensure the buttons do not stack at the same location.
- I defined `defaultButtonWidth` and `defaultButtonHeight` for maintainability.  They should be defined with `static readonly` keywords (you should do that); but, I didn't want to introduce concepts you would have to explain on.

Comment: ah.. my mistake.. for some reason, I didn't notice the scroll on your code snippet at all.   the answer I provided here is probably still valid, but could have reflect the code that was provided a bit better.

Comment: In regards to your issue with `allNumberButton_Click`, you're basically assigning the text of button that invoked the click event (the `sender`) to itself.  There is no swap occurring there. there is no validation check to determine whether a swap should or should not occur (i.e., is blank button next to the sender?).  Also, I feel it's too important to your actual assignment for me to provide an answer on.

Comment: Do you know how I would initialize an instance of Button, if you can give me an example?

Comment: it's a bit of a term soup, @BurshellAgness. But the `new` keyword relates to the constructor of a type.  When you construct a type (aka `new` it) the result is an instance of that type.  In most cases (not all), the scope of that constructor initializes the instances of that type ( which essentially dimensions, constructs and facilitates the initialization of local variables of that type).  so, a simple example of initializing an instance of a button and assigning it to a dimension 2D array of Button is `arr[0, 0] = new Button()`, that instance is not going to be at `arr[0, 1]`.

Comment: @BurshellAgness part of this answer was written while I was unaware of your entire code snippet.  Apart from my code snippet showing how to do this... You do have a means to initialize the button instances in `arr`.  It is in the scope of `InitTwoDim` function.  However, you don't seem to be calling that function in your form load event handler.

Comment: I tried arr [0,0] = new Button() and it didnt reset back to its original location. How will I set it for all buttons to go back to it's original location?

Comment: well.. I wasn't giving an instruction on how to do a reset;  I was explaining the cause of the exception.  My answer does not include (nor change) neither `allNumberButton_Click`, nor `btnReset_Click`; For, neither of those method relate to the exception you raised this question on.  This answer and solution I provided - for this exception - is for comprehensive understanding.  You will face other exceptions in `btnReset` (which I made note to), and will have to handle validation and 'blank' logic for your assignment.. but that is out of the scope of this Q&A.